# Drupal: How to theme view

Tags: drupal

i have row style set to NODE in my view. 
I need to access "title" field of every node and modify it's, say, color and print it.
Then I need to print content.
How do I loop through the nodes and access fields inside each node? I just do not know how to count total number of nodes, and how to access each field in the node.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please tell us more. do you have a list of nodes and you need to edit the titles of nodes in that list? or do you want to edit the title on the top of the page itself?

Comment: Yes, I have a list of nodes and need to add some html around every node, so my javascript function would make an accordion from this list. I don't want to use existing modules, since they does not work very well with my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to loop through the nodes, you are almost certainly better off switching to a Row style of *Fields* and using (or overriding) the the per field templates that views provides.

That said, if all you really need to do is color a field, you can do that in CSS with the existing classes that Views adds by default.

Comment: Sorry about confusion. I cannot switch to Fields styles since my node is a content type with special attachments, which cannot be represented as a field. And really I don't need to change color, I need to add javascript function on click of the node."title". I was just simplifying things.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit directly the node-NODETYPE.tpl.php, adding your html before and after the title.

Your javascript function can then check whether the node is being printed within the appropriate view or not.